# Selection between different objects in Pymol

Tags: pymol

In pymol, have two identical protein objects. One is in ribbon form and one is in surface form. I have a selection of residues on the surface object (say sele1). I would like to make it so that when you click sele1 and color it for example, it will change the color on both of my protein objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the proteins are identical you should be able to make selections on both proteins at the same time. For example:

```
select sel1, (resi 211+222+231)
color red, sel1
```

This will color resiues 211, 222 and 231 red on both proteins.
If you have other proteins in your workspace you have to adjust your selection:

```
 select sel1, (resi 211+222+231) and (protein1 or protein2)
```

Where `protein 1` and `protein2` are the molecules of interest